# Save File and Protect from User Writes

Tags: c#

I would like users to add files to a program, in a Windows Active Directory Environment.  I would then like the program to save the files to a directory.  However I would like to have the files saved to a directory where the user only has read access. Once the file is saved it is permanent and cannot be edited by the user, but they can still open it and save it locally with changes if desired.

This would be like saving the file with elevated permissions.

I don't think setting a read only attribute will do the trick as to my knowledge if the user finds the directory and file they could change that status manually.  I also don't think System.IO.File has this kind of functionality.

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Comment: In AD "normal" user would not have the possibillity to "Run as admin" on the file to change the permission, so it should be sufficient

Comment: On the folder, you can setup 'Create' and 'Read' permissions. Then users can only create new files and read existing ones.

Comment: Ah guess I was a bit ignorant.  Never really looked into or was aware of advanced file permissions so the solution to my problem may be a much easier and better than writing any code.  Found this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1145359/allow-users-to-create-files-but-not-edit-and-delete-them) which may get me what I need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems FileIOPermission library could solve this porblem so use c# sharp libary which is "FileIOPermission", you can go over from this.